# Should code inside try catch be minimized or any practice governing them?

Tags: java, design-patterns, try-catch

Assume a method `getBar` which throws a checked exception. It takes an instance of `Foo`. Foo is never used anywhere else in code and it does not throw exception and its only job is to be a parameter to `getBar`. Should `foo` be declared and initialized inside or outside a try ? Extending the question - should code inside `try` be minimal (as my second option) or wrap a block of similar related lines of code (as my first option) ?

```
try {
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   var result = SomeConnection.getBar(foo);
   return result == foo.RESULT;
} catch ( .. ) {...}

OR

Foo foo = new Foo();
try {
   SomeConnection.getBar(foo);
   return result == foo.RESULT;
} catch ( .. ) {...}
```

Comment: Is there something that's going on inside `new Foo();`?

Comment: Nothing inside foo. its never going to be cause of any exception.

Comment: Why don't you make `SomeConnection.getBar(new Foo())`?

Comment: @Christian I need foo to validate the return by a constant result == foo.RESULT;

Comment: You are right, but foo.RESULT is a constant? (because of upper case), it is an static field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ted's answer, you'd put the `foo` inside the `try` block if it had had constructor logic that could throw an exception. Other than that, in terms of performance there is no difference. I'd personally go with your first version and keep `foo` in the scope that I'm using it in.
In terms of best practice, I don't think having "minimal" code inside your try/catch makes much of a difference. On the other hand having too many try/catch blocks (or even worse, having them nested) is a bad practice.

Comment: repeating to create an event for you - Iterating my core concern - should code inside try be minimal (as my second option) or wrap a block of similar related lines of code (as my first option) ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Check my edit, I've added some clarifications, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

With your code, there are no performance issues with minimizing the amount of code inside a `try` block. The (minimal) performance impact is all in entering and exiting the `try` block itself.

EDIT: If `Foo` were something that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable` (including anything that implements `java.io.Closeable`), you should use a ["try-with-resources" statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Foo foo = new foo()) {
    var result = SomeConnection.getBar(foo);
    return result == foo.RESULT;
} catch (...) {...}
```

Note that this Java 7 language construct clearly makes `foo` local to the `try` block.

Comment: Iterating my core concern -  should code inside try be minimal (as my second option) or wrap a block of similar related lines of code (as my first option) ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - That's strictly a matter of style, as long as scoping is not an issue (that is, you don't need the variable outside the `try` block--that includes the `catch` and/or `finally` blocks). There are no performance issues to consider. Personally, I would probably put the declaration inside to emphasize the local scope of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping extra stuff in a try/catch isn't necessarily bad, but in some languages, what is thrown is a different exception type (e.g. ExceptionInvalidParameter, ExceptionUnknown, ...) and you can have multiple catch blocks for each type.  I like to wrap tons of stuff in try/catch and have a finally statement to handle unexpected exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will always execute `Foo foo = new Foo()` so you can't gain performance there, what you could do is minimize your code:

```
SomeConnection.getBar(new Foo())
```

Assuming `foo.RESULT` is a constant it could be an static constant `Foo.RESULT`.

Comment: But in he's example he needs an instance of `foo`.

Comment: What would you do about the access to `foo.RESULT`?

Comment: If `foo.RESULT` were a constant it could be a static field, so he doesn't need the instance again.

Comment: i know but developer did not code it that way